# Connection using Gmail OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail

I am trying to connect to Gmail using OAuth 2.0.

However, it is impossible to test that you can not join the risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps group.

Does Google prevent participation in the group? Or is there any other way?

The method for connection refers to the following article.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a question in google API pending email.

After that the contents of the homepage was updated.

I can not see sentences to register in the risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps group.

I developed on iOS.

The problem was that G-Mail connection authorization not added privileges at login was not done.

I solved the problem by adding G-Mail permissions.

Additional source of authority

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", @"https://mail.google.com", nil];
```

IMAP JAVA connection test : https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode